# Is it possible to combine three rows having the same color together?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Here is an [Image to support explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWOzl.png).

Column D values are highlighted with the same color if the entries are identical in this column.

In this case, for each "group" of color I should:

- add all the values of column E for a given color and enter the amount in the column J.

As you see in the picture, the amount in the column `J` is perfect when the given color occurs only in two rows (works perfectly for color red and green). 
But as soon as the color covers more than two rows, the sum doesn't reflect the sum of all the rows, but the sum of two entries at a time only.

Here is the code I wrote for this calculation:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, I As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Total_Payments As Single
    Dim Total_CashBalance As Single

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

        'Find Last row of column L
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        'Set array starting from row 2 to LastRow of column L
        arr = .Range("D2:D" & LastRow)

        For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            If .Range("D" & I).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then

                For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                    If (.Range("D" & j).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone) And (I <> j) Then

                        If .Range("D" & I).Interior.Color = .Range("D" & j).Interior.Color Then


                                .Range("N" & I).Value = "Cell L" & I & " has the same background color with cell/s L" & j

                                Total_Payments = .Range("E" & I).Value + .Range("E" & j).Value
                                Range("J" & I).Value = Total_Payments

                        End If

                    End If

                Next j

            End If

        Next I

    End With

End Sub
```

I would be really happy if you could tell me how to make this work for a number of cells in one group greater than 2 :) Thank you!!

Comment: What's the point of your array? Are the cells coloured using conditional formatting? Also, the shading seems pointless, can't you just check the text in column A for duplicates, in which case you can use a SUMIF formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SUMIF formula, inserted via VBA if necessary.

Formula in C1 copied down

```
=SUMIF($A$1:A11,A1,$B$1:$B$11)
```

[image]